# What is the font used for the slogan on this FIFA logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the font used for the phrase "For the game. For the world." in the picture below ?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quite possibly a custom typeface commissioned for FIFA.

Comment: The roman (non-italic) version has been the subject of another "What's this?" question here, but I can't find it now :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I couldn't find the previous question, [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html) managed to identify it within four questions.

It's the italic form of [**FF Cocon**](http://www.identifont.com/show?1DY):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one, [FIFA welcome (dafont)](http://www.dafont.com/fifa-welcome.font)

It might be what you are looking for. It is also available here [FIFA Welcome (cufon)](http://www.cufonfonts.com/en/font/6584/fifa-welcome)